# Moving div around and its content

Tags: css, html, positioning

I want to do the following:

The biggest Box is a div containing two imgs separated by a small space and with two small block of texts exactly beneath each one.

The problem is that I have been trying (not kidding) for at least 5 hours.

Here is my code:

**CSS**:

```css
#divPictures {
    width: 960px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    top: 520px;
    left: 200px;
    background:  url("../imgs/bg-body.jpg");
    margin: 0 0 0 -5px;
}

#divPictures img {
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div id="divPictures">
    <img src="imgs/help-out.jpg" alt="">
    <p>"TEXT HERE</p>
    <img src="imgs/what-we-do.jpg" alt="">
    <p>"AND HERE"</p>
</div>
```

---

**EDIT:**

I can't post images but is a block containing two images one next to the other and text beneath.

Comment: Ok, so what's the problem?

Comment: What do you get instead of what you want?

Comment: What I was getting was a thing that shouldn't be. An eldritch horror.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? Quick example, you can obviously add in extra CSS, or float both left and pad/margin etc...

```
#divPictures{
width: 100%;
background:  url("../imgs/bg-body.jpg");
}

.left{
width: 45%;
float:left;
}

.right{
width: 45%;
float:right;
}

.left img, .right img{
margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="divPictures">

<div class="left">
<img src="imgs/help-out.jpg" alt="">
<p>"TEXT HERE</p>
</div>

<div class="right">
<img src="imgs/what-we-do.jpg" alt="">
<p>"AND HERE"</p>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: THANKS A LOT! But because this kinda of a practice with some restrictions I cannot use neither % nor just right and down etc, only pxs and margins. The width of the page is 956px so I gonna try a few tweaks to this.

Answer (score 0):

Make new divs for images and use css atribute `display: inline-block` to tell interpreter that you want your divs in a line.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- CSS -->
<style>
div#pic
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    background:  url("../imgs/bg-body.jpg");
    margin: 5px 0 0 -5px;
}
div#pic img
{
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<!-- HTML -->
<body>
<div id="divPictures">
    <div id="pic">
        <img src="imgs/help-out.jpg" alt="">
        <p>"TEXT HERE"</p>
    </div>
    <div id="pic">
        <img src="imgs/what-we-do.jpg" alt="">
        <p>"AND HERE"</p>
    </div>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way... When i get stuck I delete it and start over. I think you would have benefitted from starting over...

**CSS**

```
<style>
.caption{
    text-align: center;
}
li{
    background: #ccd2cd;
    float: left;
    margin:5px;
    list-style: none;
    padding:5px;
}
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="http://omarhabash.com/img/feature1.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="caption">caption2</div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <img src="http://omarhabash.com/img/feature1.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="caption">caption2</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

if you dont want to use (li) list then just replace those with div classes and rename the style also to the same.

the way i have it here is a good start to a grid if thats what you are aiming for.

**http://jsfiddle.net/Mz6aF/**